# Adf login not working

Tags: jsf-2.2, oracle-adf

I am using oracle adf 12.2.1.3 and I have a problem about login. When I click login button I get no action. But if I click f5 a new page appears. I could not find the problem.

login.jsff

```
<f:facet name="center">
<af:panelGroupLayout id="pglMain"  layout="vertical"  halign="center"  inlineStyle="margin-left:-200px;margin-top:50px;">
    <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl2" inlineStyle="margin-top: 30px;">
        <af:panelFormLayout labelAlignment="start" labelWidth="150px" fieldWidth="100px" styleClass="WithColon WithVerticalSpacing"
                    inlineStyle="font-weight:600; margin-left: 230px;">
            <af:inputText id="userId" label="Kullanıcı Adı: " value="#{viewBean.userLoginInfo.userId}" required="no" secret="false"/>
            <af:inputText id="password" label="Şifre: " value="#{viewBean.userLoginInfo.password}" required="no" secret="true"/>
        </af:panelFormLayout>
    </af:panelFormLayout>
    <af:commandImageLink icon="/img_hospitalstatement/enter.png" id="HomeCI"  inlineStyle="font-size:13px" 
                partialSubmit="true" text="Giriş" action="#{viewBean.login}">
    </af:commandImageLink>                                          
</af:panelGroupLayout>
```

LoginViewBean.java

```
public String login () {
    //ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    //ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/faces/aaa/index.xhtml");
   return "goToIndex";
   // return null;}
```

login task flow

```
<task-flow-definition id="login-task-flow-definition">
    <default-activity>login</default-activity>
    <data-control-scope>
        <shared />
    </data-control-scope>

    <managed-bean id="managed">
        <managed-bean-name>indexManagedBean</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>aaa.IndexManagedBean
        </managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>pageFlow</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>loginViewBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>xxx.LoginViewBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean> 

    <task-flow-call id="xtaskflow">
        <task-flow-reference>
            <document>/WEB-INF/x-task-flow-definition.xml</document>
            <id>x-task-flow-definition</id>
        </task-flow-reference>          
    </task-flow-call>   

    <view id="login">
        <page>/login/login.jsff</page>
    </view>         

    <control-flow-rule>
        <from-activity-id>login</from-activity-id>
        <control-flow-case>
            <from-outcome>gotoIndex</from-outcome>
            <to-activity-id>xtaskflow</to-activity-id>
            <redirect/>
        </control-flow-case>            
    </control-flow-rule>    

    <use-page-fragments />
</task-flow-definition>
```

I tried redirecting and taskflow outcome but both did not work.
Note: jsf version is 2.2

Answer (score 0):

try changing `return "goToIndex";`
to    `return "gotoIndex";`

as your outcome is `<from-outcome>gotoIndex</from-outcome>`

Comment: Sorry, I had written it wrong. The problem is not that.

Comment: And also I noted that: "I both tried redirect and taskflow outcome but both did not work." Thanks...

Comment: After click the login button clicking f5 works well. But what is the problem, I could not understand...